# Apache mod_proxy parameters

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-proxy

I have a machine running Apache with mod_proxy that I'm using to proxy a local Tomcat server running on another port.

The problem is that Tomcat does not support wildcard sub-domains(whole reason for using apache/mod_proxy) and our app uses the subdomain to figure out what account the data should come from. So with that said, is there a way to pass the subdomain as a url parameter via mod_proxy?

For example, I have this:

```
ProxyPass / http://example.com:8080/
```

In a virtual host block and I can access the site from any subdomain. Would is be possible to do something like:

```
ProxyPass / http://example.com:8080/?subdomain=the_sub_domain_requested
```

Thanks for any and all help...

Mike

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to use mod_rewrite...

Comment: I am facing the same problem, could you by any chance post the mod rewrite configuration you used please?